# How to avoid calling ModelState.IsValid on every PostBack?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I pretty much always want to check if `ModelSate.IsValid` is called when I do a postback. And having to check at the start of every post back violates the DRY principle, is there a way to have it checked automatically?

Example:

```
[HttpPost("RegisterUser")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser([FromBody] UserRegisterViewModel vmodel)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)          // This code is repeated at every postback
        return ModelInvalidAction(); // Is there a way to avoid having to write it down?

    // do other things

    return StatusCode(201);
}
```

Comment: Research Action Filters

Comment: @Nkosi oh I see, will I also be able to inject a logger into that attribute?

Comment: @Nkosi nevermind, I think I can use this: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The framework provides an abstract `ActionFilterAttribute` that you can subclass.

You can use an action filter to automatically validate model state and return any errors if the state is invalid:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

You can either then use it on individual actions or register it globally

Reference [Asp.Net Core : Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#action-filters)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new BadRequestResult();
        }
    }
}
```

You can request any registered service like this `filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger>()`.
You can decorate by action filter your action or controller:

```
[HttpPost("RegisterUser")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateModel]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser([FromBody] UserRegisterViewModel vmodel)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've researched this and found the best answer I think. Even if I implement what's mentioned in the other answers, I'll still be repeating myself by having to put a `[ValidateModel]` attribute on each POST and PUT request, that's something I want to avoid, I would also like to log things if a model is invalid, other answers don't really allow for this. So here is my answer:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]
public class ValidateViewModelAttribute : Attribute, IFilterFactory
{
    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger>();

        return new InternalValidateModel(logger);
    }

    private class InternalValidateModel : IActionFilter
    {
        private ILogger _log;

        public InternalValidateModel(ILogger log)
        {
            _log = log;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (IsInvalidModelState(context))
            {
                _log.Information("Invalid ModelState: {Model}", context.ModelState.ErrorMessages());
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
        }

        private bool IsInvalidModelState(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var method = context.HttpContext.Request.Method;
            return (method == "POST" ||
                    method == "PUT") &&
                   !context.ModelState.IsValid;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable => true;
}
```

I don't want to repeat myself by having to add a [ValidateViewModel] on every `POST` and `PUT`. So I do the following:

```
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new ValidateViewModelAttribute());
        });
```

Now all `POST` and `PUT` methods are validated!!

Comment: This is accurate. I did how ever mention to you that you could have registered the filter globally. Even with Get requests the is valid will return true, so there really was not a need to check the request Http method. You could have also injected any dependencies while adding the filter globally. Either way will work. Good answer.